# OpenStack swift Token expiration swauth large file upload

Tags: c#, token, openstack, dotnet-httpclient, openstack-swift

I have openstack swift component with swauth token generation and validation middleware.
Now i have problem uploading large files into it with stream in which i can't seek in.

Now when i authenticate myself with token i ll get token with no expiration information.
I start uploading file chunks into it. This is time consuming operation and it takes a while to complete every file chunk. When my token expires in the middle of it i destroy get HTTP 401 error response from swift BUT i destroyed one chunk to get this, and since i cant seek in my input stream i can't reupload that part so i destroyed whole file just because token expiration?

I know about new swauth  X-Auth-New-Token header feature which give me new token, but revoke old one. When i do that i destroy every other client which could upload large file in the same time.

Now my question is how to authenticate without no token expiration information, or how stop streamcontent to read from stream if HTTP error is on return.

For upload i use C# HTTPClient and even expect 100-continue adding wont stop stream to roll over whole chunk.

C# code for large file upload:

```
 private readonly HttpClient m_client;
 private bool m_isAuthenticated;

 private void UploadFilePart(string partName, ChunkingStream chunkingStream)
 {

  string requestUrl = RequestUrlBuilder(m_containerName, partName);//GET URL of file
  try
        {
            StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(chunkingStream);

            //response = m_client.PutAsync(requestUrl, fileContent).Result;
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, requestUrl);
            requestMessage.Content = fileContent;
            response=m_client.SendAsync(requestMessage,
                                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Now when this happens my chunkingStream is shifted and read all data and i cant seek it back.
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                if (m_log.IsInfoEnabled)
                    m_log.InfoFormat(
                        "It seems that Auth-Token expired. Calling Authenticate method to renew token.");
                Authenticate();
                //re-upload hopefully
                response = m_client.PutAsync(requestUrl, fileContent).Result;
                //fileContent is disposed here so i have to create new one but i dont have data into it since my chunking stream already read whole fileChunk


            }
            if (m_log.IsErrorEnabled)
                m_log.Error("General exception while trying to upload file.", exception);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception while requesting client: ", exception);
        }
 }
```

Code for Authenticate method requested in comments:

```
private void Authenticate()
{
   if (m_log.IsDebugEnabled)
       m_log.DebugFormat("Requesting new token for authentication.");

   const string user = "X-Storage-User";
   const string pass = "X-Storage-Pass";
   const string authUri = "/auth/v1.0";
   const string authKey = "X-Auth-Token";
   const string storageUrl = "X-Storage-Url";

   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, authUri);
   request.Headers.Add(user, m_configuration.StorageAccount);
   request.Headers.Add(pass, m_configuration.Password);

   HttpResponseMessage response = m_client.SendAsync(request).Result;

   if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
       throw new Exception("Authentication Failed. Error: " + response);
   }

   m_authToken = GetResponseHeaderValue(authKey, response);
   //extract only uri following baseAddress
   m_storageUrl = GetResponseHeaderValue(storageUrl, response).Substring(m_configuration.Url.Length);
   //set authentication to true - we are logged
   m_isAuthenticated = true;
   //replace current default authentication header (if exists) with new token key
   m_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
   m_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(authKey, m_authToken);
   //set transfer encoding
   m_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi , from above question I need the Authenticate(); in detail can you post it.

Comment: Hi i added authenticate method here, its a simple method to authenticate via http headers.

Comment: Thanks, I will check and post the result later.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a layer of indirection that keeps track of your last chunk.  Perhaps a wrapper around either stream or stream content can do this?  Consider normally just return data from the underlying stream after copying to an internal chunk buffer, when you get the 401, call myStream.ResetChunk() and set a flag.  When the flag is set, read data from your internal buffer and clear the flag.

Comment: Nice idea but not a solution, because you have to buffer and store whole filechunk which is a huge memory problem for me because one part might have around 3-5GB and there might be many request simultaneously.

Comment: Since you never know when you'll get a 401 I think any solution on the client will involve buffering the last chunk.  You won't have multiple requests using the same stream.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious; Is there a reason you're not using the OpenStack .NET SDK? This issue, I believe, is addressed in the SDK.

Comment: Because all operation in OpenStack .NET SDK depends on Stream.Length which i am not able to provide since i am proxying Stream and i am not able to determine its lenght and it also depends on 3rd party SimpleRest lib, so i want to try it with new HTTPClient from .NET

Comment: @LightCZ I added an issue for that https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/issues/211

Comment: thanks for that... i solve it by creating different operation types (repeatable and non repeatable) and let client repeat whole upload on part fail... nasty workaround but